# Needing help sorting through a list in JAVA using Spring

Tags: java, spring, list, sorting

New and learning Java, using Spring.  Having some issues and just looking for a little direction.  I am creating a social app.  how can i sort my "deal" comments so i can only see those "deal" comments made for that specific "share"?  Users can make a share and on that share page users can make deal(more comments for that share only)  I have a list but that will show ALL the deals made, and that isn't what i want...

HOME CONTROLLER

```java
    @GetMapping("/{collectorId}/share/{id}")
    public String LetMakeADeal(@PathVariable("id") Long shareId, @ModelAttribute("newDeal") Deal theDeal,  Collector collector, Model model, HttpSession session, BindingResult result) {
        Share share = shareService.getOneShare(shareId);
        Collector collector1=collectorService.findCollectorById((Long) session.getAttribute("collectorId"));
        List<Deal> deals = this.dealService.allDeals();
        model.addAttribute("collector",collector1);
        model.addAttribute("share", share);
        model.addAttribute("collectorLoggedIn",(Long)session.getAttribute("collectorId"));
        model.addAttribute("deals", deals);
        session.setAttribute("collectorId", collector1.getId());
        session.setAttribute("collector", collector1.getId());      
        return "dealwall.jsp";
    }
```

MY DEALWALL.JSP PAGE

```
        <c:forEach items="${deals}" var="deal">
                
                
                <c:out value="${deal.collector.firstName }"/> Said:  <c:out value="${deal.deal }"/><br>
                <c:if test="${deal.collector.id==collectorLoggedIn}">
                <br>
                <a class="button button1" href="/deal/delete/${collector.id }/${deal.id }">Delete</a>
                </c:if>

                
                
        </c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0):

is delas have shareId ? then try this

```java
model.addAttribute("deals", deals.stream().filter(t->t.getShareId() == shareId));
```

using java lambda filter